# Giving error while drag and drop the custom control from the toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I created one server control(Custom control). I want to use it in my sharepoint project. I just added that custom control dll to the tool box by right click on the toolbox and add item. Now I just drag and dropped on to the visual webpart surface. It is giving following error while compilation.

`The type or namespace name 'SearchCustomControl' does not exist in the namespace 'SearchCustomControl' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'`

Is there any thing to change in web.config file or any where?

If I use like registering the control like below

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="ncc" Namespace="SearchCustomControl" Assembly="SearchCustomControl" %>`

no compilation error. After deploying into the sharepoint site it is giving me the error.
[image]

How to work with custom control dll which we want to refer in the another sharepoint project in the visual studio 2010?